# Why puppet beaker fails to resolve role "agent", whereas master/database/dashboard works just fine?

Tags: puppet

I have the nodeset definition as follows..

```
---------- Some of the attributes removed for clarity ----------------------
HOSTS:
  kpointvm1.zencite.com:
    roles:
      - master
    hypervisor : vagrant
  kpointvm2.zencite.com:
    roles:
      - agent
    hypervisor : vagrant
----------------------
```

When I run the tests it fails with following stack trace

```
----------------------
/opt/manish/kpoint_beaker/spec/spec_helper_acceptance.rb:28:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `agent' for main:Object (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /opt/manish/kpoint_beaker/spec/acceptance/001_basic_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby -I/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-support-3.1.0/lib:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/lib /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rspec-core-3.1.4/exe/rspec spec/acceptance --color failed
----------------------
```

Following is the "on" call ...

```
on agent, "mkdir -p /tmp/I-am-the-agent"
```

Surprisingly, if I change role to either master/dashboard/database it runs without
any problem.

I thought "agent" may be a reserved word, though documentation uses it,
I tried with other roles, but that fails too.

```
My environment is
----------------------
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux] (Running in RVM)
beaker (1.19.1)
----------------------
```

Any idea?

Comment: you means to say  when you change the role to master like  "on master, "mkdir -p /tmp/I-am-the-master" "  It Works !...

Comment: Yes. Not only that, if I set the role to database or dashboard it works fine. Even I was surprised by this behavior. All the wiki samples uses agent, so I was expecting it to work. Not only that, the wiki documentation claims that I can even have any other role. That too does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Josh on puppet-user google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-users/_mEAFTBtST4/V1lN5TdktoIJ) it seems that I should be using agents and not agent.

There could be more than one agent and hence agents.

The wiki has one example which has correct example of "on agents".
However, some of the DSL call refers to agent and I was tripped by one of these calls.

## Update:

After some trial and error I could also use the custom role. The trick is to specify custom role as symbol when referring them in "on" call, e.g. "on :customerole 'do something'".
Looking at the code, it looks likes that Beaker should define methods for these custom roles but somehow it is not doing so.